On descending a section of a morphism between schemes from formal completion to étale local
Here's the case, which arises from the context of doing infinitesimal deformation. Given a DVR $(S,\mathfrak{m},\kappa)$ we have the completion $\hat{S}$ with respect to $\mathfrak{m}$. Say we have a quasi-projective morphism $q:X\rightarrow S$ which admits a section over the formal completion
$$
\mathrm{id}:\hat{S}\rightarrow\hat{X}\rightarrow\hat{S}
$$
where $\hat{X}$ is the formal completion of $X$ with respect to $q^*\mathfrak{m}$. Then

can we conclude the existence of a section for $q$
or can we conclude the existence of a section for the base change of $q$ over an étale cover $S'\rightarrow S$, namely $q':X\times S'\rightarrow S'$
or can we conclude the existence of a section for the base change of $q$ over the henselianzation $S^\text h\rightarrow S$ (resp. strict henselianzation $S^\text{sh}\rightarrow S$)?

I'm not so familiar with this topic so I'll be more than thankful if someone kindly provides some examples.

I believe the third bullet point is an equivalent statement of the Artin approximation theorem. The second bullet point follows from the third bullet point since the spectrum of the henselization is the inverse limit of all étale covers with a section over the special point and since $X$ has finite type over $S$ the set of maps to $S$ commutes with that inverse limit. The first bullet point is certainly false - consider a variety with a $2$-adic point but no $3$-adic point and take $S$ to be $\mathbb Z$ with every odd prime inverted.

@WillSawin Yes the second and third points are equivalent in some extend, I'm just enumerating the different statements of the desired property. And thank you for the rejection of the first point. I'll look at the Artin's approximation theorem later.

Artin's theorem (actually due to Greenberg for DVRs) gives a positive answer to the second and third questions when $S$ is excellent (equivalently, the extension of fraction fields for $S\subset\hat{S}$ is separable). There are counterexamples otherwise.

@LaurentMoret-Bailly Where can we find the counterexamples?  I was going to suggest that we only need Neron desingularization, not Artin/Greenberg.  If there are counterexamples, then I guess my suggestion is wrong.

@JasonStarr In characteristic $p>0$, it may happen that there is  $\xi\in\hat{S}\smallsetminus S$ such that $\eta:=\xi^p\in S$: see Example 11 in section 3.6 of "Néron Models" (or maybe Nagata's book). Now take $X=\mathrm{Spec} (S[X]/(X^p-\eta))$.

Sorry, $X$ was a bad name for the variable!

Regarding Néron desingularization: this should work (without excellence assumption) if the generic fiber of $X\to S$ is smooth.
